# Openshift - Error occur x509 certificate signed by unknown authority after create a tag for image stream

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I can create an application and build it successfully. However, I can't create a new for tag for an image of the application. The following is the command I used to create the tag and the result I got:

```
oc tag docker-registory.svc:5000/myproject/myapp@sha256:231d3371ad687233f7a6140c67a314c416105b424c19f28b124ca298989998b3 myproject/myapp:test

Tag myapp:test set to docker-registory.svc:5000/myproject/myapp@sha256:231d3371ad687233f7a6140c67a314c416105b424c19f28b124ca298989998b3.

root@018fdb569d8a:/# oc get is
NAME DOCKER REPO TAGS UPDATED
myapp docker-registory.svc:5000/myproject/myapp latest,test 5 minutes ago

root@018fdb569d8a:/# oc describe is
Name: myapp
Namespace: myproject
Created: 7 minutes ago
Labels: app=myapp
Description: Keeps track of changes in the application image
Annotations: openshift.io/generated-by=OpenShiftNewApp
openshift.io/image.dockerRepositoryCheck=2019-01-07T03:44:42Z
Docker Pull Spec: docker-registory.svc:5000/myproject/myapp
Image Lookup: local=false
Unique Images: 1
Tags: 2

latest
no spec tag

docker-registory.svc:5000/myproject/myapp@sha256:231d3371ad687233f7a6140c67a314c416105b424c19f28b124ca298989998b3
5 minutes ago
test
tagged from docker-registory.svc:5000/myproject/myapp@sha256:231d3371ad687233f7a6140c67a314c416105b424c19f28b124ca298989998b3

! error: Import failed (InternalError): Internal error occurred: Get https://docker-registory.svc:5000/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```